# I'm using a bit of jQuery code to allow click and drag creation of boxes, how can I create them programatically?

Tags: jquery

In [this bit of jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/mWdvQ/), you can click and drag in the white area to create boxes.

How can I add the boxes programatically? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new  with the correct class and css styles and append to the appropriate parent element on the page...

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('ui-boxer')
                .css({ border: '1px solid white', 
                       background: 'orange', 
                       padding: '0.5em', 
                       position: 'absolute', 
                       'z-index': 100,
                       left: 150, top: 150, 
                       width: 50, height: 50})
                .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, and the html after the box is added looks okay, but for some reason the box doesn't actually appear in the canvas? Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7bJak/

Comment: If you want the box positioned relative to the canvas, you need to change position: 'relative'. Right now it's absolutely positioned with respect to the page. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7bJak/2/