# How can I call this function that's within a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This jQuery plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd3s8/) has the following function attached to the stop event (which I think is initiated from the _mouseStop event):

```
$('#canvas').boxer({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var offset = ui.box.offset();
    ui.box.css({ border: '1px solid white', background: 'orange', padding: '0.5em' })
      .append('x:' + offset.left + ', y:' + offset.top)
      .append('<br>')
      .append('w:' + ui.box.width() + ', h:' + ui.box.height());
  }
});
```

Is there a way I can call this exact function from the code (with no input from the user), and provide it with an equivalent for the ui object that is passed as a parameter (I have the variables required)? I know I can programatically create the boxes [in other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130573/im-using-a-bit-of-jquery-code-to-allow-click-and-drag-creation-of-boxes-how-can), but I'm interested to see if I can do it this way because it will make some other things go much easier. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Try `trigger()`. You can trigger the mouseStop event with it.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would I call the trigger() on? I'm pretty new to jQuery and can't quite work out how this plugin works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function letsDoThis(e) {
  $(e).boxer({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var offset = ui.box.offset();
      ui.box.css({ border: '1px solid white', background: 'orange', padding: '0.5em' })
      .append('x:' + offset.left + ', y:' + offset.top)
      .append('<br>')
      .append('w:' + ui.box.width() + ', h:' + ui.box.height());
    }
  });
}

letsDoThis('#canvas');
```